# XDEBUG not working PHP 7.3 Win 10 x86

Tags: php, xdebug

1. Download https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html 
   (xampp-win32-7.3.0-0-VC15-installere.exe) can't find any x64 xampp for windows.
2. Does not return any download link. https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

PHP Version 7.3.0
System  Windows NT DESKTOP-NDF3MVL 10.0 build 14393 (Windows 10) i586
Build Date  Dec 6 2018 01:51:18
Compiler    MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017)
Architecture    x86
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File   C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
PHP API 20180731
PHP Extension   20180731
Zend Extension  320180731
Zend Extension Build    API320180731,TS,VC15
PHP Extension Build API20180731,TS,VC15
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   enabled
Thread API  Windows Threads
Zend Signal Handling    disabled
Zend Memory Manager enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  disabled

3. Manually install https://xdebug.org/download.php
   PHP 7.3 VC15 (64 bit) or PHP 7.3 VC15 TS (64 bit)

add line to php.ini:
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
zend_extension = php_xdebug-2.7.0beta1-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll

PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'php_xdebug-2.7.0beta1-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.0beta1-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_xdebug-2.7.0beta1-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: There is no 64 bit XAMPP. So why are you trying to use 64 bit XDebug? Use a 32 bit version.

Comment: for PHP7.3 can't find 32-bit version https://xdebug.org/download.php and XAMPP no 64-bit version

Comment: PHP 32 bit can be downloaded from [PHP For Windows: Binaries and sources Releases](https://windows.php.net/download/)

Comment: I following tutorials and want to use XDebug for Visual Studio Code, don't know what to do with PHP for windows

Comment: {shrug} We are not here to provide tutorials for you.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same issue. The xdebug site currently only has 64-bit versions for PHP 7.3; the PECL site has the 32-bit versions needed for XAMPP.

I'm sure this will be corrected once xdebug 2.7 is production, but in the meanwhile the PECL site (https://pecl.php.net/package/xdebug/2.7.0beta1/windows) is the work around.

Answer (score 0):

You can download 32bit binary for PHP73 here:
https://pecl.php.net/package/xdebug/2.7.0beta1/windows

Comment: Author already attempted that particular download.

Comment: Why do you think so?
Author used only 64bit version from xdebug site. For now 32 bit version is only available on this pecl site.